# Is there a way to log who upload or change a spesific file? (centos)

Tags: centos, ssh, ftp, hacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server’s been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

There is a file that keeps infected with [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14727/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-malware-code) code. I can't figure out why. So I want to log who upload or change the file. Is there a way to log who upload or change a spesific file?

PS: There is no FTP login. We only use SSH and Plesk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. The audit subsystem has some pretty neat accounting features.

Running the following command will audit changes to the file:

```
auditctl -w /my/specificly/modified/file.txt -p w -k "suspect file change"
```

This will setup a watch on this file, whenever it is modified by a write the change will be logged, and be logged quite extensively.

You can check the logs doing:

```
ausearch -i -k "suspect file change"
```

This will return output such as:

```
type=PATH msg=audit(05/08/2012 17:32:32.353:13118) : item=1 name=/tmp/test.txt inode=5767528 dev=fd:00 mode=file,644 ouid=root ogid=root rdev=00:00 obj=staff_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 
type=PATH msg=audit(05/08/2012 17:32:32.353:13118) : item=0 name=/tmp/ inode=5767169 dev=fd:00 mode=dir,sticky,777 ouid=root ogid=root rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 
type=CWD msg=audit(05/08/2012 17:32:32.353:13118) :  cwd=/home/matthew/Testbed/C/fanotify 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(05/08/2012 17:32:32.353:13118) : arch=x86_64 syscall=unlinkat success=yes exit=0 a0=0xffffffffffffff9c a1=0xb540c0 a2=0x0 a3=0x7fff50cfba20 items=2 ppid=13699 pid=2773 auid=matthew uid=root gid=root euid=root suid=root fsuid=root egid=root sgid=root fsgid=root tty=pts0 ses=2 comm=rm exe=/usr/bin/rm subj=staff_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0 key=some file
```

If you want something stronger, you can go for something that, say watches for any deletions by a user not normally inclined to do that. For performance the more specific the rule the better..

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S rmdir -F auid=78 -F dir=/var/www/vhost
```

The -F defines the filters and the -S defines the syscalls, the more filters the less intensive it is on the kernel to track it. So in this case I filter on the user (apache), the vhosts directory and arch. Arch becomes important b64 being 64 bit b32 for 32 bit.

You can set these up long-term by putting the rules in /etc/audit.rules.

Comment: And with `auditctl -l` command can see all rules.  
And so with these commands can remove rules for no watch files:
`auditctl -W /my/specificly/modified/file.txt -p w -k "suspect file change"` and 
`auditctl -d exit,always -F arch=b64 -S unlink -S rmdir -F auid=78 -F dir=/var/www/vhost`

Comment: `auditctl -D` for delete all rules.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using CentOS, this is something you could use SELinux for. You could re-label the file in question as something like `httpd_config_t` like so: `chcon -v --type=httpd_config_t /the/html/file/in/question.html`

Then SELinux will log an error to /var/log/audit/audit.log . If you're running SELinux in "permissive" mode it will allow the change; if you're running in "enforcing" mode, it will not allow the change.

Take a look at: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux to learn more. Note: by default, SELinux is running and enforcing in CentOS, so you should just have to change the label on this one file.